# Helm uninstall removing CSIDriver before deployments made pod stuck at "Terminating"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, csi-driver

I'm using a CSIDriver with three workloads and Helm to manage my cluster.

When i run helm uninstall {chart} these three pods get stucked at terminating status forever. Looking at the logs I saw that the CSIDrivers is been delete before the deployments, and it is making their volumes' tearDowns crash. Check the error below:

```
Error: "UnmountVolume.TearDown failed for volume \"spire-agent-socket\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/csi/80621856-bf9a-4406-be77-06cc31242e87-spire-agent-socket\") pod \"80621856-bf9a-4406-be77-06cc31242e87\" (UID: \"80621856-bf9a-4406-be77-06cc31242e87\") : kubernetes.io/csi: mounter.SetUpAt failed to get CSI client: driver name csi.spiffe.io not found in the list of registered CSI drivers"
```

Comment: doing a "delete pod --force" isn't the best solution to this problem. I am looking for a solution with helm

Comment: I'm facing similar problem, but looks like it's not because CSIDriver is deleted before pod is terminated. I added pre-install hook to CSIDriver and tried helm install but pods are still stuck in terminating state though CSIDriver exists. "Error:" you've pasted in question is it from pod or something else?